# Responsive Navigation bar troubles

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navigationbar

Trying to make my webpage as responsive as possible, having trouble with my navigation bar though. I want the logo and nav included in the size of my container, but the nav bar won't stretch out the full width of the container, or it will overflow. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Win Or Go Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/nav.css" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="blueline">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="logo"><img src="../images/image1.jpg" /></div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" target="_self"><strong>ITEM 1</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="" target="_self"><strong>ITEM 2</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="" target="_self"><strong>ITEM 3</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="" target="_self"><strong>ITEM 4</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="" target="_self"><strong>ITEM 5</strong></a></li>
                <li><a class="blue" href="" target="_self"><strong>SPORTS</strong></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

@font-face {
    font-family: "Nevis";
    src: url(http://www.beatthatfordrums.com/win/extras/fonts/nevis.ttf) format("truetype");
}
body {
    background-color:#F4F4F4;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:0.5%;
}
#blueline {
    background-color:#0086be;
    height:57px;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
}
.container {
    width:60%;
    max-width:2570px;
    min-width:700px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
#logo {
    width:5%;
    height:57px;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
}
nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    height:57px;
}
ul {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}
ul li {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul li a {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color:#767676;
    display: block;
    font-family: "Nevis", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 20px 57px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #F4F4F4;
}
ul li a:hover {
    background:#f0f8fb;
    color: #0086be;
}
ul li a.blue:hover {
    background:#f0f8fb;
    color: #0086be;
}
ul li a.blue {
    background:#0086BE;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but from what I gather it looks like your problem is that you want the nav items to be *fluid*, yet you've essentially given them *static* dimensions with the rule `ul li a { padding: 20px 57px 20px; }`.

If you want your elements to fill the available space without overflowing, you can give them widths in percentages. (And make sure those widths add up to 100% of the parent (I see, for instance, that `#logo` and `nav` are siblings, but logo has a width of 5% and nav a width of 100% -- adding up to 105% of the parent ---- this will mess with you probably ----))

You might also consider some other tactics, like shrinking font-size or reducing padding at smaller widths.

Comment: Correct, I did have nav at 95%, but i forgot I was playing around with it and changed it to 100.
I understand what you are saying, I'm not sure how to size my <li> items without padding using static dimmensions. I tried padding using percentages and that did not seem to work at all.